# API in my main.py flask application doesn't work after dockerizing the app on Windows

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I dockerized my Flask application on windows. I use Docker Desktop to run docker. In windows, to join the container you can't use localhost but the ip "192.168.99.100". So, after dockerizing app, I try to reach one API from this ip address, but the request goes in timeout:

[image]

The strange thing is that I enabled debug inside my main.py file, but when I run docker-compose up, it seems that it doesnt' run the application in debug mode:
[image]

My Dockerfile, in which I specified where to find my main.py app (the same path) as FLASK_APP:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

ENV FLASK_APP=main.py
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose: 
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
        - FLASK_APP=main.py
        - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=cred.json
```

docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile are in the same path.

main.py, where you can see at last lines that I run it in debug mode:

```
import os, io
import logging
import json
import jinja2
import requests
import re

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file, abort, session, redirect, jsonify, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask.helpers import make_response
from google.cloud import tasks_v2, bigquery, firestore, kms_v1, storage

import httplib2shim
import env_config
from audience_manager import AudienceManager
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import mysql.connector
import cron
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth import app_engine
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

from exceptions import AuthenticatorException, UserVisibilityNotFoundException, InvalidEmailException, \
    NoneEmailException
from jwt.exceptions import ExpiredSignatureError
from authlib.integrations.base_client import MismatchingStateError
from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from oauth2_authentication import Oauth2Authentication

from services import db_service
from spreadsheet import Spreadsheet
from ggm import start_ggm_check, ggm_module
import secret_manager_module

from flask.globals import g

from task_module import CloudTask

import iap_service

httplib2shim.patch()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print("#### abc")
        
    g.auth_user = "giacomo.brunetta@external.stellantis.com"


@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def ciao():
    print("## hello")
    return 'ok'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Flask version in requirements is 2.0.1

Comment: Do not post text as image.
Also, di you map a port of your container to your host machine ?

Comment: as you can see by my docker compose yes, I map the port

Comment: Oops, indeed, I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

is never executed (see [What does if **name** == "**main**": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more information).

---

To get things working, you have two options.

1. Use the flask command line tool:

   ```
   ...
   EXPOSE 8080
   ENV FLASK_APP=main.py
   ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1
   ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=8080
   CMD ["flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0"]
   ```
2. Use python:

   ```
   ...
   EXPOSE 8080
   CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
   ```

   and

   ```py
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your Docker container it is executing the `CMD` you specific in the `Dockerfile` as:

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

It isn't running the line of Python script where you:

1. Set it to run in debug mode
2. Tell it to start listening on port :8080

This is why neither of those things are actually happening. Flask is starting on its default port of :5000 and with debug mode disabled.

To fix it, update the `CMD` in the Dockerfile to either:

use the arguments you need to the `flask run` command

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", " --debug"]
```

or run your `main.py` script directly:

```
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Personally, I like having the port specified in the `Dockerfile`, as you also need to set it there with `EXPOSE`, so it keeps it in the same place if you ever need to change it.